# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.io.InputStream] and content type [application/octet-stream]

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to call a webservice from my program which accepts the string data and returns the `inputstream`. But when I have written the client code I am getting no suitable `HttpMessageConverter` found for response type `class  java.io.InputStream` and content type `application/octet-stream`. So Please help me.

Here is my client code

```
public InputStream zipFolderWithSubsequestFolder(String folderToBeZipped, String transactionId) {

    LOGGER.debug("DataShareServiceClient :: zipFolder() : Calling  zipFolderWithSubsequestFolder Service -> folderToBeZipped: "
                + folderToBeZipped);
    String header = getServiceName();

    // RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    url = url + "/" + "rest" + "/"
            + "DataShareService" + "/"
            + "zipFolderWithSubsequestFolder";


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(folderToBeZipped, headers);

    InputStream response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, InputStream.class);
    // Make the HTTP POST request, marshaling the request to JSON, and the response to a String
    //ResponseEntity<InputStream> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, InputStream.class);
    //InputStream result = response.getBody();
    return response;

}
```